# How do I install Java 7? I keep getting redirected to Java 8

Tags: java-7

I am trying to install Java 7 because I have some software that is failing under Java 8.

I have googled quite a bit and any link I go to that looks promising redirects me to Java 8.

It seems Oracle is hiding the place where the older versions are kept because they don't link to them on their current version download page.

Comment: To those who are voting to close: This is different from the 'duplicate' answer because it is specific to Java 7.   I did not think of googling for old version, I figure other people will have the same problem and now they will get a hit when they google.

Comment: More-specific questions are often considered duplicates, especially if the answers work for the more-specific question. Also, a duplicate is not inherently bad as they can serve as a sign-post towards another question and answer. However, this question is also a request for an off-site resource, which is considered off-topic and is the reason the other question was closed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that requests for offsite resources are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the actual link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

Most of the external links will focus on the latest one(java8).So always use oracle to solve java relates issues.

Comment: You beat OP to self answering, +1 in my book.

Comment: @JonnyHenly This answer is 3 minutes younger.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you are correct, now I feel stupid.

Comment: I kept googling for java 7, and kept coming up with dead ends.  Then I figured out I should google "old version of java" and I got  good hit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to download older versions of Java:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html

The key to finding that was to google for "older version of java" rather than Java 7.